# $u$ harmonic then $u^{-1}\{u(x_0)\}$ is infinite for $N\ge 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

> Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be an open, $u$ harmonic in $\Omega$
>   and $x_0\in\Omega$. Show that if $N\ge 2$ then $u^{-1}\{u(x_0)\}$ is
>   infinite. What about $N=1$?

The $N\ge 2$ makes me think that somehow this problem on the line collapses because of dimension $1$, and for higher dimensions it's like I'm in a plane and can walk in many directions.

I don't see how to connect this with the fact that $$\sum\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2} = 0$$

For the one dimensional case, $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = 0$$

for all $x$ in some $\Omega$, so it's an interval. This is the same as saying that the function has second derivative $0$ at an open the interval. If it were just a point I'd say the function might have an inflection point, but in fact it's in an entire open interval.

Let's first think of the most basic example: $u(x) = 1$. The set $u^{-1}(u(x))$ is the entire interval on which the function is harmonic (even more, but let's focus on that). So in this case it is infinite. I guess I should find a counterexample with some non obvious function. Anyone has ideas?

Comment: A perhaps different way to look at this is the following: Replace $u$ with $v(x) = u(x) - u(x_0)$. Then the question is asking: "If $v$ is harmonic in $\Omega$ with one zero then it has infinitely many zeros."

Comment: Also, if you are not familiar with many of the properties of harmonic functions then this might be a strange problem, because harmonic functions behave in many strange ways. In one dimension it is easy, because the harmonic functions are just lines.

Comment: wouldn't this be true for any smooth function from a higher dimensional space into the real line?

Comment: @Marco: No, think of critical values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $u^{-1}(u(x_0))$ is a finite set $F.$ Then, as Marco wrote, there is an open ball $B(x_0,r)$ such that $u\ne u(x_0)$ in $B(x_0,r)\setminus \{x_0\}.$ Since $B(x_0,r),  B(x_0,r)\setminus \{x_0\}$ are both connected, their images under $u$ are, respectively, intervals $I,J$ by the continuity of $u.$ But $J=I\setminus \{u(x_0)\}.$ So we've removed $u(x_0)$ from $I$ and still have an interval. The only way that can happen is for $u(x_0)$ to be the largest value of $I$ or the smallest value of $I.$ In either case we have $u\equiv u(x_0)$ in $B(x_0,r)$ by the max/min principle for harmonic functions, contradiction. Therefore $u^{-1}(u(x_0))$ is infinite (and in fact it must be uncountable).

Comment: $u(\Omega)$ and $u(\Omega-F)$ are connected because of what exactly? I guess that's because they're image of connected by something with some properties. So since $u$ is real valued, both $u(\Omega)$ and $u(\Omega-F)$ are intervals. The rest I didn't understand. Why $u(x_0) = \max_\Omega u$ or min? Why then $u$ is $u(x_0)$ in all points?

Comment: I edited my answer and hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, by making $\Omega$ smaller, suppose $\Omega$ is a ball centered at $x_0$ and $u^{-1}\{u(x_0)\}=\{x_0\}$ and we derive a contradiction. Since the value of $u(x_0)$ is the average of the values of $u(x)$ on the ball, we conclude that there must exist $x_1,x_2 \in \Omega$ such that $u(x_1)<u(x_0)<u(x_2)$. Connect $x_1$ to $x_2$ via a path that doesn't go through $x_0$. By the intermediate-value theorem, there must exist $x_3$ along the path such that $u(x_3)=u(x_0)$, a contradiction.

Comment: what you mean by the average of values of $u(x)$ on the ball? And where did you use the hypotesis that $u$ is harmonic?

Comment: That's a property of harmonic functions that the value $u(x_0)$ equals the integral of $u(x)$ over any ball centered at $x_0$ divided by the volume of that ball.